# ad goup list.txt piped to Get-ADGroupMember

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Hi I'm new to powershell. I have text file with ad group list and I want list all users for each group. I tried pip line :

```
Get-Content '.\test list.txt' | % { Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive $_ } | select name
```

but in result i get single column with all users list belongs to all groups in text file.

how i can get csv table with all groups names in column heading and users list below each group name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ( not tested ):

```
Get-Content '.\test list.txt' | 
SELECT @{N="Group Name";e={$_}},@{N="Members";`
E={ (Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive $_) -JOIN ';' }} | fl
```

Comment: Thanks C.B looks good. Do you know how I can get members name (sAMAccountName) instead of Distinguished Name?

Comment: @user2118913 try to change this: `(Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive $_ | select -expa samaccountnane)` I can't test it...

Comment: Doesn't work :(. I tried as well (Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive $_ | select -name) but no joy.

Comment: Try to read member that exposed `(get-adgroupmember <NameOfAGroup>)[0] | get-member` and look for properties can fit your needs

Comment: there is property "name" but command get-adgroupmember shows by default DN property. Do you know how to change DN to Name in command output (select name doesn't work).

Comment: try `(Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive $_ | % { $_.name }) -join ';'` or `(Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive $_ | % { $_.samaccountname }) -join ';'`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you. It requires PS3.0:

```
Get-Content .\list.txt | % {(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive).Name | Out-File -FilePath "$_.txt"}

$hash = @{}
Get-Content .\list.txt | % {$hash["$_"] = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive).Name}
$hash
```

I don't use CSV very much but I bet hashes are easy to format into CSV files.